# XSL For-each Total Count

Tags: xml, for-loop, xslt, web, xslt-1.0

I am trying to return a total count using for-each in xsl. For example in one instance, there are 8 iterations or car_types and I'd like to return a total count for $car_types[0] + $car_types[1] + $car_types[2] + $car_types[3] ...and so on. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks!

```
<xsl:for-each select="$car_types">
    <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/webpage/results/cars/*[type = $car_types[$counter]])" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please show an example of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Store the main document with

```
<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>
```

outside of the `for-each`, then you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="$cart_types">
  <xsl:value-of select="count($main-doc/webpage/results/car/*[type = current()])"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

That assumes that `$cart_types` contains nodes from a document different to the primary, main input document. And it assumes your paths are correct as shown, you will have to show an input sample to allow us to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/webpage/results/cars/*[type = $car_types])" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use**:

```
count(/webpage/results/cars/*[type = $car_types])
```

**The above means**:

Give me the count of all children-elements of all `/webpage/results/cars`, whose type is one of the types contained in `$car_types`

**Read more** about the semantics of the XPath general equality operator **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)** and **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons)**.